# How to handle file inputs as variables in Python/wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a working script that I am attempting to port over to a GUI.  I'm new to programming so a lot of this code may be hack-ish.  I'm open to suggestions on general practices and methods!  Below is my working text-based version of the function I'd like to port:

```
def InitUI(self):
    self.pdf = None
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.pdf = PDFWindow(self, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    sizer.Add(self.pdf, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

    pdfPicker = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,message='Please select the PDF to resize.', wildcard='*.pdf', size=(500,20))
    btnSizer.Add(pdfPicker, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=5)
    btnSizer.AddStretchSpacer(3)

    self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Enter Scale (decimal percent):')
    self.field = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="0.5", size=(50,20))

    btnSizer.Add(self.label, 0, wx.ALL, 8)
    btnSizer.Add(self.field, 0, wx.ALL, 8)

    # .... more GUI code (buttons, etc.)

def resize_file_main(resize, fileout, self, e=None)
    file1 = ask_file_name('resize1', 'input', '', inputDir)
    fileout = ask_file_name('resize1', 'output')
    input1 = str(file1) + '.pdf'
    dir1 = os.path.join(inputDir, input1)
    backup1 = os.path.join(backupDir, str(file1) + '.pdf')

    resize_file(input1)

    try:
        shutil.move(dir1, backup1)
        print input1, "has been successfully moved to the backup folder.\n"
    except:
        print_error('\nThe PDF you entered is opened elsewhere.  The file was not backed up.')
        print "Please move your scanned PDF from /input to /backup or run the backup utility.\n\n      Press enter to continue  ....  "
        print raw_input('')
    continue

def resize_file(filename, filename2 = None):
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    fIn1 = file(os.path.join(inputDir,filename), 'rb')

    inp1 = PdfFileReader(fIn1)
    p1 = inp1.getPage(0)
    p1.scale(.5,.5)
    output.addPage(p1)

    if filename2 is not None:
        fIn2 = file(os.path.join(inputDir,filename2), 'rb')
        inp2 = PdfFileReader(fIn2)
        p2 = inp2.getPage(0)
        p2.scale(.50,.50)
        output.addPage(p2)

    outputStream = file(os.path.join(validateDir,str(fileout) + '.pdf'),"wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
    fIn1.close()
```

Here's my question.  I'd like to get rid of all the text-based user interaction.  How do I take object-based inputs and turn them into passable variables?  I've been able to implement wx.TextCtrl to enter user input and wx.FilePickerCtrl to select the PDF for the input.  Now how do I:

- Pass these as variables to my resize_file function?
- Set the output location?
- Set the backup location + input PDF name?
- Pass the wx.TextCtrl values (for scale) to my resize_file function?

This also may be my problem:

1. I have a InitUI function doing all the wxPython stuff
2. The button within InitUi function calls resize_file_main
3. resize_file_main just handles inputs/outputs and moving the final
   files around.  It also calls resize_file.
4. resize_file is a function that is re-used in several other areas
   of the script.  It takes in the various inputs/outputs and actually
   resizes the PDF(s).

Is this a bad flow?  I wasn't sure how to combine resize_file_main and resize_file because the input/outputs with the different areas that call resize_file are different.

Thank you for your help!  I know it's convoluted!

Edit:  Thank you!  I believe I have enough information to move forward.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this specific question:

> How do I take object-based inputs and turn them into passable
>   variables?

You access the controls and call the appropriate methods:

```
self.resize_txt.GetValue()
self.file_input.GetPath()
self.outfile_input.GetPath()
```

To pass them to your resize, function, just pass those values to your resize_file function.

```
resize_file(self.file_input.GetPath(),
            self.outfile_input.GetPath())
```

You're asking too many questions here TBH.  You should start with one, and create others as you progress.

What the heck, I have time to kill before lunch!  I'll give you a few pointers.

Let's look at this function:

```
def resize_file(filename, filename2 = None)
```

Looking at this function, I really have no idea what the inputs are to the function.  It says filename and an optional filename2.  Which of these is being resized?  How do I know what each parameter does?  You did not document this function, which made me dig off into your code to try to determine what it does.

So, I dug off into your code...  And it appears that this particular function resizes and possibly appends pdfs.  Notice how in your code, you execute the same code twice?

```
fIn1 = file(os.path.join(inputDir,filename), 'rb')

inp1 = PdfFileReader(fIn1)
p1 = inp1.getPage(0)
p1.scale(.5,.5)
output.addPage(p1)

if filename2 is not None:
    fIn2 = file(os.path.join(inputDir,filename2), 'rb')
    inp2 = PdfFileReader(fIn2)
    p2 = inp2.getPage(0)
    p2.scale(.50,.50)
    output.addPage(p2)
```

Don't do this.  Use the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.  You should have a loop, as the algorithm is basically the same.  (Can't illustrate the loop atm, running out of time before lunch, maybe when I get back :P)

You could even get fancy and have your function take an indefinite amount of PDF files.  Check this snippet out:

```
def resize_file(*args):
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    for filename in args:
        fIn1 = file(os.path.join(inputDir, filename), 'rb')
        inp1 = PdfFileReader(fIn1)
        p1 = inp1.getPage(0)
        p1.scale(.5,.5)
        output.addPage(p1)

    outputStream = file(os.path.join(validateDir,str(fileout) + '.pdf'),"wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
```

Ok, I lied, I tried to squeeze this in before lunch.  The code above may not work out of the box, but it should point you in the general direction.  You should add error catching to check for when no arguments are passed (among other things).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #initGUIStuff
    ....
    self.resize_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnResize)

 def OnResize(self,evt):
    resize(self.resize_txt.GetValue(),self.file_input.GetPath(),self.outfile_input.GetPath())
```

maybe?

not sure what you are asking to be honest ...